# Unable to locate package boot-repair in 14.04

Tags: apt, boot-repair

I've tried to install boot repair and failed

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
```

The error is:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package boot-repair
```

I've never had this error before on other versions of Ubuntu or Mint, though.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following commands to install boot-repair in Ubuntu 14-04 :-

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo sh -c "sed -i 's/trusty/saucy/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-trusty.list"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Comment: Error on line 2, `sed: can't read /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-trusty.list: No such file or directory`  Am I doing this wrong? (I'm running off of live usb stick 14.10 to perform the repair...)

Comment: same error es above

Comment: @zipzit Same problem. Did figure it out?

Comment: After spending a whole lot of time installing Ubuntu on different systems I've come to two conclusions.  On a hard drive a clean install is best and always worked.  When trying to install Ubuntu on a bootable flash drive, I was better off using a desktop computer, disconnnecting ALL hard drives before bootup and install from one flash drive to another.  That gave me best results.  And on that specific problem from Nov 2014, I'm sorry, I just don't remember what I did to get things running.  I know I got it running, but I don't remember the details. Sorry.  Good luck with it.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem.

Boot-repair doesnt support 14.04 yet https://bugs.launchpad.net/boot-repair/+bug/1267702

My solution is to use `boot-repair disk iso`, it works for 14.04 http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/

Comment: @ship07: How to install the boot-repair-disk-64bit.iso on my machine, any commands required ?